# How do I make a GitLab Wiki searchable?

Tags: reactjs, gitlab, markdown, jsx, gitlab-ci

I'm making a GitLab Wiki for work and my team wants it to be searchable. I'm writing the pages in markdown and using ReactJS to build the pages themselves.

Is there any way to add a search bar that searches just the wiki page? I don't want it to search the entire GitLab repository, just the wiki.

I've done some initial research, but I haven't been able to find anything.

The goal is to have a search bar at the top right of all the pages so you can search for things on other wiki pages.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54457813/954777) that explain how to export the wiki to a static site with an integrated search feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure on what type of answer you are wanting, but you`re going to need all of the data from the Gitlab wiki, then you're going to need to find a way to filter that data based on whatever they are typing in the search bar.

If you rephrase your question a bit and make it more clear about what you want, we could probably be a little more of assistance.

Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

Get a web crawler. Norconex is an opensource one.